# Alignment is css with list keep all in one proportion

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have an issue when it comes to alignment keeping everything in the table with in a straight line. Without exposing the table and keeping everything with in one line.
As you can see in the image all of the table with the icons is straight while mine are not straight.

As well as keep the icons same size as the font.

For example my desired output:
[image]

What I get:

```css
.mainlist{
  display: inline;
}

a {text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

.ha-bg-parallax {
    background: url(../img/bg.JPG) no-repeat fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ha-bg-parallax .ha-parallax-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


nav ul a.active {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


 <div class="ha-bg-parallax text-center block-marginb-none" data-speed="20" data-type="background">
       <div class="ha-parallax-body">
   <div id="home" class="section scrollspy">
     <div class="section white">

       <div class="row center">

          <img class="responsive-img valign left" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/325a3d7ccb21e729b51d8a0b343901ba.jpg?s=250&r=pg&d=edlaika.net">

          <ul>
      <li class="mainlist"><i class="fa fa-key fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li class="mainlist">Keybase</li>
      <li class="mainlist"><a href="https://keybase.io/husky">@husky</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
   <li class="mainlist"><i class="fa fa-github fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
   <li class="mainlist">Github</li>
   <li class="mainlist"><a href="https://github.com/edlaika">@edlaika</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
   <li class="mainlist"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
   <li class="mainlist">BitBucket</li>
   <li class="mainlist"><a href="https://bitbucket.org/edlaika">@edlaika</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
   <li class="mainlist"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
   <li class="mainlist">Email</li>
   <li class="mainlist"><a href="mailto:howl@teamhusky.net">howl@teamhusky.net</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
   <li class="mainlist"><i class="fa fa-steam fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
   <li class="mainlist">Steam</li>
   <li class="mainlist"><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/edlaika/">/id/edlaika</a></li>
   </ul>

     </div>
     </div>
  </div>




        </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use the `fa-fw` Font Awesome's class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to include jQuery into your program since you are including bootstrap. See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Edit: Now that you have jQuery in and it runs, what shows is the 3 social media tabs, and you want those aligned left instead of center I take it?

You'll want to have them to the right of the picture then, not underneath it also while left-aligning them since they're centered (hence why they are not straight). You also want to just reduce the size of the items and it should tone down the size of the font and the image associated.

If you change the line `<img class="responsive-img valign center"` and make center into left you can get your image on the left. As for changing the icon sizes you need to go into the css stylesheet that is being used for the icons. See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_icons.asp)

Comment: I included jQuery  I just forgot to add it here.

Comment: Yes I would like them to be in the center but to be aligned to one in other just like in the image example above.

Answer (score 1):

Omit the .fa-3x class so that the icons become font-size. Add .fa-fw class to make them fixed-width, looks better in lists like this. No need for so many `<ul>` elements. Those are elements inside one single list. Better to keep it simple. Here a quick proposal.

```css
.profile-img {
  border-radius: 999px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.ha-bg-parallax {
  background: url(../img/bg.JPG) no-repeat fixed;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ha-bg-parallax .ha-parallax-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
nav ul a.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="ha-bg-parallax text-center block-marginb-none" data-speed="20" data-type="background">
  <div class="ha-parallax-body">
    <div id="home" class="section scrollspy container">
      <div class="section white">



        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s6">

            <div class="profile center">
              <img class="profile-img responsive-img valign center" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/325a3d7ccb21e729b51d8a0b343901ba.jpg?s=250&amp;r=pg&amp;d=edlaika.net">
              <h4>edlaike</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at bibendum felis. Nam a porttitor sapien. Donec egestas vulputate urna, quis ullamcorper risus viverra non. Maecenas id erat commodo, aliquam lacus vel, elementum orci. Vestibulum
                tristique luctus felis, quis auctor purus maximus nec.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col s6">
            <div class="mainlist">




              <p>
                <i class="fa fa-key  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Keybase
                <a href="https://keybase.io/husky">@husky</a>
              </p>

              <p>
                <i class="fa fa-github  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Github
                <a href="https://github.com/edlaika">@edlaika</a>
              </p>

              <p>
                <i class="fa fa-bitbucket  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                BitBucket
                <a href="https://bitbucket.org/edlaika">@edlaika</a>
              </p>

              <p>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Email
                <a href="mailto:howl@teamhusky.net">howl@teamhusky.net</a>
              </p>
              <p>
                <i class="fa fa-steam  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Steam
                <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/edlaika/">/id/edlaika</a>
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```